# How do i use a premade material as the base color of Principled BSDF

Tags: materials, blenderkit

So this is my premade material

[image]

I want to connect it as the base color of my Principled BSDF, because i want the material only to be applied to a specific parte of the face which is being guided by a normal map

[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: You don't need a principle BSDF, you could use a mix shader, the black and white image that you are using for the Normal as a factor and output that as main color

Answer (score 0):

You can't plug a mix shader to the base color, because the mix shader output data is not color data.
You have to use the "Mix" node set to "color" to mix whatever are the base color inputs in the other shaders, then you can plug the mix color node in the base color.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, but still doesn't work, should i do this way https://i.ibb.co/hHbS6f7/image.png

Comment: No, Mix color node takes in color data, not shader data.
You have to mix whatever is being used as Base Color in the previous materials, not the mix shader.
You can't just plug anything into anything, you have to plug appropriate data into each input.